# How to fix this sort_by in collection_select works in the browser but returns "comparison of String with nil failed" error in Capybara

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capybara, minitest

I've been stuck on trying to write a system test for a form that manually works in the browser.

I have a `Speaker` model that `has_one :individual`. The form field looks like this:

```
<fieldset>
  <%= form.label :speaker, "Who said it?" %>
  <%= form.collection_select :speaker_id, Speaker.all.sort_by(&:full_name), :id, :full_name %>
</fieldset>
```

The custom `full_name` method in the `Speaker` model looks like this:

```
  def full_name
    if individual
      "#{individual.first_name} #{individual.last_name}"
    end
  end
```

The `if individual` conditional is a smell, but without it, I get this error:

```
Minitest::UnexpectedError: ActionView::Template::Error: undefined method `first_name' for nil:NilClass
```

If I add the `if individual` conditional then the error looks like this:

```
Minitest::UnexpectedError: ActionView::Template::Error: comparison of String with nil failed
```

I'm confused because I'm using a similar pattern to sort collection selects by a `full_name` in other models, but this is the only one that raises an error in the system test. Also everything works as expected when I manually test in the browser.

I can also access the the `first_name` `last_name` and `full_name` methods in the `Individual` model in the console, no problem.

This also doesn't cause an error (and I can use `:full_name` to display the name in the browser, but it's just not alphabetical:

```
<%= form.collection_select :speaker_id, Speaker.all, :id, :full_name %>
```

[image]

How can I fix this error in Capybara? Or is there a better way to return `Speaker.all` in the collection_select sorted alphabetically?

---

Update:
I simplified this by not passing the Quote / Individual relationship through a Speaker model. Now, my `Quote` model `belongs_to :individual` and `Individual` `has_many :quotes`. This is also working in the browser, but I'm getting the same error with my system test:

```
<ActionView::Template::Error: undefined method `full_name' for nil:NilClass>
```

Here's one of the tests that is failing with this error...

```
require "application_system_test_case"

class QuotesTest < ApplicationSystemTestCase
  setup do
    @contributor = users(:contributor)
    @contributor_quote = quotes(:contributor_quote)
    @category = categories(:rock_and_roll)
    @field = fields(:music)
    @topic_one = topics(:recording)
    @topic_two = topics(:songwriting)
    @individual = individuals(:john_lennon)
    @group      = groups(:the_beatles)
  end

  test "visiting the index should be accessible to all" do
    visit quotes_path
    assert_text @contributor_quote.body
    click_on @contributor_quote.body
    assert_current_path quote_path(@contributor_quote)
  end
end
```

My `Individual` model has this method in it:

```
def full_name
  "#{first_name} #{last_name}"
end
```

And this is the part of the view that is causing the failure:

```
  Speaker: <%= @quote.individual.full_name %>
```

If I include `save_and_open_page` the error looks like this...

[image]

I tried adding `.strip` as Thomas' answer suggested, but that's not helping.

Again, the only problem is this system test. It works fine in the browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without actually seeing any of the test code the error is coming from it's impossible to know for sure, and I have no idea where Capybara is fitting into this.  I'm guessing that what you have is a Speaker model that seems to depend on there being an `individual` associated with it, but that's not actually enforced anywhere so when you create the speaker instance in your test without an associated individual it's not being flagged as invalid. If Speaker is supposed to support there not being an associated `individual` then your issue is that your `full_name` method is returning nil when a string is required.  To fix that you could do

```
def full_name
  "#{individual&.first_name} #{individual&.last_name}".strip
end
```

to give you the full name when `individual` does exist, and an empty string when it doesn't

Comment: Thanks Thomas, I updated my question to include more info. I simplified my associations, but I'm still getting a very similar answer. I also tried adding `.strip` to no avail. Also shared my test. Is this something you might have seen before?

Comment: @LeeMcAlilly You've changed your data structures, but still have the same issue.  You're not correctly setting up the data necessary for your test.  The ` undefined method `full_name' for nil:NilClass` error is telling you that the `@quote` instance being rendered in the view doesn't have an `individual` instance associated with it.  It works for you in the console because you're running that in the development environment where you've created valid data, but you're not creating valid data in the test environment.

Comment: yep, you're right. It was a dumb typo in my fixtures causing all of these problems. Appreciate your help in troubleshooting this. I learned more about how fixtures work as a result !